# Как встроить javascript на сторонний сайт?

Tags: javascript, интеграция

Может не корректно сформулировал вопрос, сори.

Столкнулся с задачей изменить внешний вид на стороннем сайте. Суть сводится к тому, чтобы появилась возможность добавления в DOM новых элементов. На подобии расширений для браузера Download manager или SaveFromnet. Они добавляют свои кнопки на такие сайты как YouTube, Контакт и прочие.

Если запускаю скрипт через консоль браузера - все идеально работает. Но не могу понять как это реализовать в фоновом режиме. Причем только на определенных сайтах.

Гугл молчит. Подскажите, куда копать. Как эта область вообще называется. Буду благодарен за полезные советы и ссылки!

Comment: > На подобии расширений для браузера

> Но не могу понять как это реализовать в фоновом режиме

Очевидно, написать расширение для браузера. Копать, соответственно, [тут](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html) и [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Extensions).

Comment: Да, чуть не забыл. Есть уже готовые расширения типа [GreaseMonkey](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey), которые значительно облегчат вашу работу.

Comment: http://www.greasespot.net/ - Greasemonkey (FireFox)  
http://tampermonkey.net/ - Tampermonkey (Chrome, Opera Next)  

Позволят добавить пользовательские javascript'ы для определенных сайтов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение найдено с помощью данных расширенй:
[tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/) и 
[greasespot](https://www.greasespot.net/)

За подсказку спасибо @venzell